# CSS3 Animate Height to Dynamic Amount

Tags: css, dynamic, jquery-animate, height, css-transitions

I'm trying to use strictly CSS(3) to animate the height of a `div` larger and smaller, based on which class it has.  The problem is that the larger height could/should change depending on how much content is in the `div`.

Here is my current code:

```
 .failure-info{ width:97%; 
    padding:.2em .5em 0 .5em; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    cursor:pointer; 
    -moz-transition-property: height; -moz-transition-duration: .7s;
    -webkit-transition-property: height; -webkit-transition-duration: .7s;
    transition-property: height; transition-duration: .7s; 
 }
.failure-info.height-small{ height:16px; }
.failure-info.height-large{ height:85px; }
```

This works well, except when more content gets added to `.failure-info` and the inner-html goes over the `85px` height for the large class.  Content is added, and class is changed via jquery, so I'm not adverse to doing this with a jquery function if it can't be accomplished with pure CSS; however, I'd like to keep it CSS if possible!

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: someone just posted an answer with a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/2QcCC/2/) to use max-height rather than height as the transition-property.  This seems to work so whoever that was should repost their answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following an answer that was published for this question and then removed (for some reason) I was able to get the results I wanted.  Here is the code:

```
.failure-info{ width:98%; padding:3px 1% 0 1%; overflow:hidden; cursor:pointer; max-height:16px;
   -moz-transition-property: max-height; -moz-transition-duration: .7s;
   -webkit-transition-property: max-height; -webkit-transition-duration: .7s;
   transition-property: max-height; transition-duration: .7s; 
 }
.failure-info.height-small{ max-height:16px;  }
.failure-info.height-large{ max-height:150px; }
```

So, essentially I'm using the max-height property rather than the height property for the transition effect, as long as the max-height is relatively close to whatever the total height of the element should end-up being (after all the necessary elements have been added inside) then the animation will time itself appropriately.